# DCN recommender system recommend function

Tags: tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I am working on a recommender system using DCN, following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/dcn

But his tutorial lacks the recommend function, which I can pass the user_id and command, it can output the prediction. Similar to what's happening the basic_rating tutorial
https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/main/docs/examples/basic_ranking.ipynb

Is there a way to do that in DCN as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the dcn model for a custom dataset but followed the tutorial.

Following is the model training code (*copy pasted from the dcn tutorial*):

```
dcn_result = run_models(use_cross_layer=True,
                        deep_layer_sizes=[192, 192])


def run_models(use_cross_layer, deep_layer_sizes, projection_dim=None, num_runs=5):
    models = []
    rmses = []

    for i in range(num_runs):
        model = DCN(use_cross_layer=use_cross_layer, 
                    deep_layer_sizes=deep_layer_sizes, 
                    projection_dim=projection_dim)
        
        model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate))
        
        models.append(model)
        
        model.fit(cached_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=False)
        
        metrics = model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)
        
        rmses.append(metrics["RMSE"])

    
    mean, stdv = np.average(rmses), np.std(rmses)

    return {"model": models, "mean": mean, "stdv": stdv}
```

After this you can choose a particular model from the list of models trained, for example:

```
model = dcn_result['model'][3]
```

**Then you can pass in a dictionary to the model with your input features to get recommendations with their scores, for example:**

```
test_ratings = model({"user_id": np.array(["00012a2ce6f8dcda20d059ce98491703"]),
"customer_city":np.array(["sao paulo"])})

for product, score in test_ratings:
       print(f"{product}: {score}")
```

**This will produce the output:**

```
43ee88561093499d9e571d4db5f20b79: [[1.3206882]]
```